# Magento2 : Google map API json file decode using curl

Tags: magento2, google-map

```
<h1>hello this is phtml file</h1>
<?php $address=$_GET['location'];//manhattan


$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
 $url="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&key=".$block->getApiKey();
echo $url;
```

from above code i am getting this url

if hit that url in  browsers other tab it will display json data i.e https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Manhattan&key=AIzaSyBr3mn7y42_iHMTcE_5zEJk_uSGCFXIFGk

i have to fetch that data in php variables mainly longitude and latitude for setting in my map any suggestion

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: you want to get map URL or want to get latitude and longitude from variable?

Comment: if you hit the url you will find lat and long in geometry of that api  file .I only need those variables value after that i will manage

Comment: are you get your data from JSON or other api you have called ?

Comment: google map API i haven't created any json file on localhost that file is generated by google maps

Comment: you can use CURL to get this json in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have URL and just want to get Data use CURL as below.

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Manhattan&key=AIzaSyBr3mn7y42_iHMTcE_5zEJk_uSGCFXIFGk";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
$jsonToArray = json_decode($response,1);
print_r($jsonToArray);
```